# Object Map select by key goal

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

Given a number, I need to know in which goalpost it is.

I think this snippet illustrates what I need:

```
const breakPoints = {
  '>1104': 4,
  '830<1104': 3,
  '556<830': 2,
  '<556': 1
}

const calculateHowMany = ( currentSize, breakPoints ) => {
  ...
  ...
  return howMany
}

let A = calculateHowMany( 1200,  breakPoints ) // should be 4
let B = calculateHowMany( 920,  breakPoints ) // should be 3
let C = calculateHowMany( 300,  breakPoints ) // should be 1
```

Comment: Try putting it into words.

Comment: can you help me do that?

Comment: I have no idea what you want.

Comment: Make `breakPoints` look like an array, `[[1104, Infinity, 4], [830, 1104, 3], ...`

Comment: the scope/context is too big to put in here, but I need to determine how many children will there be in a specific size.

Comment: Start with structuring the data properly. As written, you'll have to parse the property names and such. I Always prefer arrays of objects with fixed property names to represent collections. Think of something like:` [{"amount":4,"min":1104, "max":null},{"amount":3,"min":830, "max":1104},...];` Then your solution becomes a simple loop to check if 1200 is between min and max. If so, return the amount.

Comment: The input appears to be a `width`, he want to return the id of the `breakpoint` comparing to upper and lower bounds, for example: this `'556<830'` represents a lower bound of `556` and upper of `830`. But I consider very bad idea storing that way...

Comment: @Shilly your comment seems to be right on point with what I need. If you care to put it into an answer I will mark as correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As described in my comment, smart data structures and dumb code works better than the other way around:

```js
const breakpoints = [
  { "amount": 1, "min": 0, "max": 556 },
  { "amount": 2, "min": 556, "max": 830 },
  { "amount": 3, "min": 830, "max": 1104 },
  { "amount": 4, "min": 1104, "max": Infinity }
];

const calculateHowMany = ( currentSize, breakPoints ) => {
  return breakPoints.find( breakpoint => breakpoint.min <= currentSize && breakpoint.max > currentSize ).amount;
};

let A = calculateHowMany( 1200,  breakpoints ) // should be 4
let B = calculateHowMany( 920,  breakpoints ) // should be 3
let C = calculateHowMany( 300,  breakpoints ) // should be 1

console.log( A, B, C );
```